# How to include only one dependency project classes in final jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use Maven to build my `MyProject`. There are several other projects which are used as library projects for '`MyProject`'.

In **pom.xml** of `MyProject`, I defined those library projects as dependencies of `MyProject`. One of the Library project is named "`OneLibProject`":

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xxx.OneLibProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>OneLibProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  ...
</dependency>
```

Under `MyProject` root path, after I run : `maven clean install` a **MyProject.jar** is generated. But those classes defined in library projects(dependencies) **are not included** in this **MyProject.jar**.

Each library project also have its own pom & can generate its own jar.

Now, what I want to do is I want to have my **pom.xml** in "`MyProject`" to be configured so that the generated **MyProject.jar** file contains the classes of `OneLibProject` and classes of `MyProject`. **Other library project classes are not included**.

How to achieve this?

Comment: google jar-with-dependencies

Comment: pos dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674784/maven-plugin-to-create-executable-jar-with-dependencies-not-unpacked-jar-with-j

Comment: @BenjaminDale though no answer was really accepted. But to add some value to my comment - if you have a war-project maven provides [a way to create skinny war-files](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html)

Comment: @RomanVottner Nice, I don't think I'm aware of this. I shall be using this for future Maven built war files :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven-assembly-plugin and configure which dependencies to include in jar in assembly descriptor's dependencySet section.

Assuming you have project y and z. Add this plugin to y's pom

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

place this assembly.xml in scr/main/assembly

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <includes>
                <include>test:y</include>
                <include>test:z</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

run `mvn install` in z

run mvn package assembly:assembly in y

if all correct you will get y-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar in target folder. It will contain y and x classes only.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample please?

Comment: I got all dependencies' classes be included in one jar, that's not what I want. I only need one dependency's classes to be included.

Comment: test is the groupid?